# Are blenders and food processors usually rated in terms of average wattage or peak wattage?

Tags: blender, food-processor

I saw the Ninja blender and food processors were advertised as "peak wattage 1500." Some other blending machines at a similar price range had lower wattage, but most of them did not say "peak." In electrical engineering (my field), there is peak values and other values (such as operating values).

Is it reasonable to assume most blenders and food processors are advertising their peak wattage (and not a lower wattage under load or RMS power)?

I simply want to compare apples to apples when selecting one to buy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no electrician, but as Amps = Watts/Volts they had better be telling you the peak load, or you risk blowing fuses.

1500W on 240v = 6.25A.
1500W on 120v = 12.5A

This isn't like cheap hi-fi where they tell you the peak figure to make you think it's going to be louder ;)